# Why is can't num scan the intended value in c?

Tags: c, integer

I have to scan this file which partly contains

```
SNOL
INTO num IS 8
INTO res IS 9
```

and the output of the code below is

```
Program starts...
Set value of num to 0
Set value of res to 8
input msg
```

which is wrong because `num` should be 8 and `res` should be 9

why is it `num` scanning 0 instead of 8?

and why doesn't the code work anymore if I assign number to num and number to res?

```
num = number;

//Tokenizer functions//
bool isLowerCase(const char *object)
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(object);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(object[i] >= 'a' && object[i] <= 'z') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//function to check if character is Float.
bool objectFloat(const char* object) {
    //check if 1st character is a digit, if not then return false, 
    otherwise
        return true.
        if(!isdigit(object[0]))
            return false;

    // Check if the 2nd character to the last are digits or periods.
    // If not, return false otherwisereturn true
    int periods = 0;  //initialize how many periods in the object to zero
    int i;
    //if character is a period then increment periods.
    for(i = 1; i < strlen(object); i++) {
        if(object[i] == '.') {
            periods++;
        }
        //return false if character is not a digit
        else if(!isdigit(object[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // return true if there is only one period.
    return periods == 1;
}

//function to check if character is a keyobject.
bool isKeyobject(const char* object) {
    char keyobjects[11][11] = { "SNOL", "LONS", "INTO", "IS", "MULT", "BEG",
    "PRINT", "ADD", "SUB", "DIV", "MOD" };

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        // Check if object is equal to keyobjects at index i
        // If yes, return true
        if(isLowerCase(object))
            return false;
        if(strcmp(object, keyobjects[i]) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    //object is not equal to any of the keyobjects so return false
    return false;
}

//Function to check if every character is an integer
// If not, return false otherwise return true
bool objectInt(const char* object) {

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(object); i++) {
        if(!isdigit(object[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool objectIsVariable(const char* object) {

    // Check if alphanumeric character & lower case
    // If not, return false
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(object); i++) {

        if(!isalnum(object[i]) && !isLowerCase(object)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {

    FILE *s_path = fopen("test.snol", "r");

    int number = 0;
    int num, res;
    if(isKeyobject(object) && strcmp(object, IsitSNOL) == 0) {
        printf("Program starts...\n");

    }
    else if(isKeyobject(object) && strcmp(object, IsitINTO) == 0) {
        printf("Set value of ");
    }

    if(objectInt(object)) {
        number = atoi(object);
    }
    else if(objectFloat(object)) {
        number = atof(object);
    }
    if(objectIsVariable(object) && strcmp(object, IsitNum) == 0) {
        //if float

        printf("num to %d\n", number);

        num == number;
    }
    else if(objectIsVariable(object) && strcmp(object, IsitRes) == 0) {
        //if float
        printf("res to %d\n", number);
        res == number;
    }
    else if(isKeyobject(object) && strcmp(object, IsitBEG) == 0) {
        printf("input msg\n");

        scanf("%s", msg);

        fscanf(s_path, " %s", &object);
        printf("INPUT(%s): %s\n", object, msg);
    }
}
} // END MAIN -----------------------------------//
```

Comment: Might I ask where the rest of your code is? Or better a [mcve]?

Comment: Debug this by inserting a printf of `object` in every program path. Especially you want a print when you assign to `num`. I guess you'll see that the code doesn't execute in the order you think

Comment: I was still sitting there bewildered at what `isKeyobject` or `objectFloat` or `objectIsVariable` might possibly be... We can't help you unless you help us help you by posting an actual copy of your code in a compilable form with the minimum code necessary to allow us to compile an reproduce the problem. That is a MCVE.

Comment: I have put printfs of object and it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to be that you read the number **after** the variable name but you do the print **before**.

So your sequence is:

```
Keyobject INTO
objectIsVariable num  // Now you print the value
objectInt             // Now you read the value
```

You need to postpone the printing until you have actually read the value.

This is not a very elegant solution, but you can try like:

```
int flag = 0;

if(objectInt(object)) {
    number = atoi(object);
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        num = number;
        printf("num to %d\n", number);
    }
    else if (flag == 2)
    {
        res = number;
        printf("res to %d\n", number);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Illegal flag\n");
    }
    flag = 0;
}


if(objectIsVariable(object) && strcmp(object, IsitNum) == 0) {
    flag = 1;
}
else if(objectIsVariable(object) && strcmp(object, IsitRes) == 0) {
    flag = 2;
}
```

Comment: @Robyyyn what change did you make? I didn't propose any solution. I only described what is going wrong

Comment: else if (isKeyobject(object)&&strcmp(object, IsitINTO)==0){
     
        
        else if (objectIsVariable(object)&&strcmp(object, IsitNum)==0){
          //if float
          
          printf("num to %d\n", number);
          
          num==number;
         }
         if(objectInt(object)){
           
      number=atoi(object);
     }
     else if(objectFloat(object)){
      number=atof(object);
     }

Comment: it works now, thank you. why is there another problem about the code not working when num = number; is used?

Comment: @Robyyyn you can't have code like `num = number;` in global space. Code needs to be inside a function

Comment: It worked but it after I entered a message at BEG, the code won't work anymore.

Comment: @Robyyyn It's probably time to ask a new question with your updated code